# Laptop screen periodically turns on and off while using external monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi

When I connect my laptop to my TV via HDMI cable the following list of events occurs;

1. Laptop screen goes black
2. Windows "something plugged in" sound plays
3. After approximately 5 seconds windows "something unplugged" sound plays
4. Laptop screen comes back on
5. After approx. 2 seconds; start from STEP 1.

A little background on the problem;

The first time I hooked up my laptop to the TV; everything was normal except for the resolution which was a little off, so I changed the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1920x1200.
After I changed and confirmed the new settings; this problem started to occur.

I believe its related to some saved resolution information about the device in some configuration file or registry and when I connect it, windows automatically tries to set its resolution to 1920x1200 which causes the connection to be reset by TV (thus unplug.wav and laptop screen coming back on) then re-try it all over.

List of things I've tried so far;

1. Tried the same HDMI cable on other sources (just to make sure it works properly)
2. Connected my laptop to a desktop monitor. (my TV is wide screen 46", monitor is a typical 22")
3. Removed and reinstalled my video card driver (7670M Radeon)
4. Installed a dummy display device so that when I plug my TV it wouldn't automatically tries to connect with it which would allow me to change its default resolution. But the combobox was disabled at my laptops resoulution (1366x768).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem, albeit not completely.

```
CTRL + ALT + F3
```

is your friend!. With this key combination, I've been able to activate my primary display device (my laptop monitor) instantly. So the instant my laptop screen goes black, I used this combination to turn it back on, and change the secondary device's resolution.

Now I can project my display to both screen or extend it. I still can't use 'projector only' option but it's acceptable.